# Is Parallels supposed to be the pilot for an actual series?

Tags: production, parallels

The movie [Parallels](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3479316/) is on Netflix, and gives the impression that there is more to follow. Even the opening credits give more of a "series" than "movie" impression.

So my question is, **is there any secured information if Parallels is (or was) going to be an actual series?** Was this supposed to be the pilot for an upcoming TV-series or maybe a pilot of a failed series that was released on its own then? If yes, then is there any information about that series, e.g. if it will use the same actors, build upon the movie story-wise, or how the episodes are going to be structured?

Comment: Related question on the Sci-Fi SE: ["Have Netflix officially commented on the future of Parallels as a TV series?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86698/31029).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The show seems to be stuck in development hell but the discussions over the future of the series are evidently still continuing.

> Trying to make the series happen....
>
> – [Christopher Leone (@ChristophrLeone)](https://twitter.com/ChristophrLeone/status/711571643739410432) on Twitter, 20 Mar 2016

Comment: So does this mean it *was* indeed supposed to become an actual series? You might want to elaborate on that point first *before* bringing up Twitter discussions that seem a little out of context (and hard to read behind an entirely strikethrough-covered answer).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - As you can see from the twitter trail, the maker has hopes of making it into a series. He's been in talks with multiple studios for over a year.

Comment: Ok, can you put that into a more coherent Twitter history, rather than a reversely-ordered revision history that's all striked through then? At the moment it reads more like 5 different attempts at an answer, rather than a Twitter trail.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Hence the "update" headers to give it structure.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I made it pretty clear that I was happy with the formatting. No-one else has complained about the strikethroughs. I'm somewhat at a loss why you'd ignore me.

Comment: Well, 3 people downvoted and two people complained directly. There is absolutely *no* readability to this answer. I can see *zero* benefit of hiding an entire answer behind strikethrough. Do you mean your whole answer is just wrong and shouldn't be read? In that case, why include those parts at all?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Fair enough. Better now?

Comment: Well, now it isn't much of an answer at all, which is a pity considering the many valuable information that it seems to ignore. But granted, it's fully readable now indeed, which is certainly progress.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Feel free to post your own answer if you think the answer had valuable info that I'm ignoring.

Comment: And of course if people want to see the original post they can mosey on over to [SFF:SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86698/31029) where there's a copy.

Answer (score 1):

[From the writer's Twitter](https://twitter.com/christophrleone) on 18 March 2015:

> We are hellbent on making more PARALLELS! We're figuring out the next
>   steps now but I should have news to share very soon.